# Strange container div behaviour

Tags: css, html

I'm asking this for learning purposes; there aren't any negative aspects on this behaviour, but I just wonder if this could have any negative consequences in the future.

So I have a container div: `content_wrap`, which has two other div's: `side_bar` and `main_content`. The container div is `980px width`, and is used to center its contents using `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

It's doing this correctly, however, when I was debugging the page (in Firefox), I noticed that the browser renders the div as being `0x0px` and renders the parent div off-screen. However, it does position the child divs correctly. See this JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fsXp/7/

I Googled this and most of the answers have something to do with `floats` and are solved by using `clear:both`, but I don't use any floats. I did notice that if I change the `main_content` div from `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`, the `content_wrap` is displayed correctly. Or I can fix it by setting a `height` for `content_wrap`.

I don't actually need to be able to see the content_wrap, so there isn't really a problem, as it is doing its job in means of centering the child divs. I just wondered if it would be a bad practice to leave it like this? Is it a bad thing, or does it matter?

Comment: Is there any reason to position the blue div absolutely? http://jsfiddle.net/7fsXp/11/ - This is pretty broad, it's whether the flow of the page matters to you. Also, include your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding other elements to this HTML and enjoy the horror :D
There are actually many things in your code, that I wouldn't do. First of all, when an element is with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` its layout is "ignored" by other elements or in other words cannot "push" any element and that is why your container is having 0 height. It's like they are ethereal (best explanation ever, I know).
You should check this article on positioning -- http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

The fact that they are in the place you expect them to be is that there are actually no other elements in the HTML and the `absolute` element is positioned relatively to the `body` and so is the `fixed` one (but that's what elements with `position: fixed` always do). Looks what happens when I add some other content to the parent div -- http://jsfiddle.net/7fsXp/13/

So long story short - you shouldn't form your layout with absolute or fixed elements if you can do it without them.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` and `position: absolute` take the elements out of the flow, so using either of these positions on all child divs will collapse the parent div entirely.

If you have content below a collapsed div, it will flow up and over/under that content like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/7fsXp/14/)**.

You don't need to position the main_content div absolutely, but you'll need to change a few things to top align the sidebar and main_content.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7fsXp/12/)**

Since sidebar is fixed, it's using the document, not the container div as a reference for `top`, while `main_content` would use the body (unless you add `position: relative` to the container). Getting rid of the body's default padding/margin will fix the small alignment difference.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main_content {
    //remove position: absolute;
    margin-top:70px; //top: 70px won't work unless you specify position
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are willing to do, but because the default `position` for `div` is `position: static;` changing the `position: relative;` will avoid the collapse of parent div.